# Python 3 How to find variable named as string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry, i don't know how to name this problem correctly :/
I have variables for each letter in alphabet. When i check word for each letter i want to add +1 to the variable which is named the same as a letter im at currently.
I want it to work like this:
`locals(letter) += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the variables by doing this...

```
locals()[letter]
```

But the fact you need to check the value of variables named after strings indicates a bad design choice.

Instead you should store those values in a `dict`.

```
letters = {
    'a': 0,
    'b': 0,
    'c': 0,
    ...
}

letters['a'] += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not wise to have variables created for all letters in English and using them (26 variables! Sounds **huge**).

Better go for `Counter` approach:

```
from collections import Counter

word = 'hello'
print(Counter(word))
# Counter({'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 1})
```

If you need all letters count:

```
import string
from collections import Counter

all_letters = string.ascii_lowercase
word = 'hello'
d = dict.fromkeys(all_letters, 0)
d.update(Counter(word))
print(d)
```

Comment: I need each letter count for other calculation so this would only make it more difficult i guess, this was my first idea when i started, thanks tho :)

Comment: @StanisławBorkowski, I edited my answer. Use the last code snippet in that case.

Comment: better, but still not what i need XD
https://pastebin.com/kgqbfDD7
this is what im doing

Comment: its for this (don't spoil it and write your answer please) https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/2